# Using a secret, private action

Tags: github-actions

I am giving a coding lesson where students can upload answers to our quizzes using personal, private repositories. So here's how the repository structure of my organization looks like:

```
my_organization/student_1_project
my_organization/student_2_project
my_organization/...
my_organization/student_n_project
```

I would like to run a private GitHub Action at any `push` on a student repository. This Action would run partial reviews of the student's work, and notify me of stuffs. Its code would need to be **unreachable** from students, of course, otherwise providing hints & solutions.

I have three questions:

1. Can my workflow in e.g. `my_organization/student_2_project` be to use a private action `my_organization/my_private_action`? It seems like yes thanks to `actions/checkout@v2` (see [here](https://www.pinel.cc/blog/2019/11/02/private-github-actions#updated-on-06182020)) but pretty sure that involves playing with keys or tokens or secrets - I'm not so at ease with that and currently get an error although it does exist:

```
Error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/my_organization/my_private_action' not found
```

2. Can it prevent the student (owner/admin of `my_organization/student_2_project`) to see the code in `my_organization/my_private_action`?
3. With the same constraints, could the private action be hosted in another organization?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I understand the restrictions:

1. Using an action from a private/internal repository currently isn't supported directly, see [this issue](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/74) on the roadmap. A possible workaround is adding a personal access token with access to the private repo that contains the action and then checking it out like this:

   ```yaml
   - name: Get private repo with action
     uses: actions/checkout@v2
     with:
       repository: yourorg/privateactionrepo
       ref: master
       token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
       path: .github/actions
   ```

   You can then use the action in another step like

   ```yaml
   uses: ./.github/actions/actionname
   ```

   The PAT can be a secret on the org level so you don't have to add it to every single student repo.
2. Since the student's repo has access to the PAT, they can use it to create a workflow that checks out the private repo and does whatever they want with it – upload its contents, print every file etc.
3. As long as the PAT has the permissions to check out the repo containing the action, the action can live anywhere, including in another organization.

Alternatively, if you want to prevent your students from seeing your action, you could add a workflow to your students' repositories that sends a [request to the GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event) and then have a trigger in your action on the [`repository_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) event.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you elaborate on the last part of your answer? The idea is to `POST` a request to my private action repository, hence triggering it to run. Any data I would need would be under `client_payload`. But there again, for the `POST` to actually work, the request from the student repository needs a somewhat token to identify himself no?

Comment: @Arnaud I'm actually not 100% sure what kind of authentication you need when sending a webhook event - the docs imply that you need a token with `repo` scope, at which point we're back to the problem of this allowing a student to use the token to check out that repo. Maybe you do need an external service to forward webhook events from your student repos, something like Zapier: https://zapier.com/page/webhooks/

Comment: Github moved the issue to Q4 2021 – Oct-Dec. Let's hope it won't move again. This feature is the key solution to this problem

Comment: @Elwyn Annoyingly, the issue has been updated to only mention "internal" repositories, which only exist on Enterprise accounts, and not "private", which non-Enterprise organizations have. The original text is still visible in the edit history of the issue description.

Comment: @BenjaminW. you're right, I did not see it. The history of the issue is totally crazy for a feature that would have seemed to be out-of-the-box..

Comment: @arnaud How about you add a new answer with the updated information? I'll update this one to point to it. The edit is an almost complete rewrite.